# Loop Through Sub Dir

Tags: vba

I have the following code that requires me to manually update the "DateFolder" each time for my directories to move.

How do I update this so all the subfolders in the "source folder" are moved based on my code?

The folder structure is:

```
   Date 1
     |
  Folder 1
     |
   Files
   Date 2
     |
   Folder 1
     |
   Files
```

```vb
Sub MoveFolder()
    'move any directories with all their contents listed in DIR_UPDATE
    ' from the source folder to the destination folder
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim destinationFolder As String
    Dim mysql As String
    Dim DateFolder As String

    DateFolder = "20160331"

    mysql = "SELECT * from Update"

    sourceFolder = "C:\Test\" & DateFolder & "\"
    destinationFolder = "C:\Test\New\" & DateFolder & "\"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet(mysql)

    'look for folders from UPDATE and move them from sourcefolder to destinationfolder
    While Not rs.EOF 

        UPdateFolder = sourceFolder & rs!Update '

        'must tell dir that sourceFolder is a directory
        If Dir(UPdateFolder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then

            objFSO.MoveFolder Source:=UPdateFolder, destination:=destinationFolder '
        
            Debug.Print "Move Folder Command Complete From: " & UPdateFolder & _
              "......To: " & destinationFolder & rs!Update
     
        Else

        End If
        
        rs.MoveNext
    
    Wend

    Debug.Print "Move Complete " & Now()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you think about this code? I checked it in my OS.

```
Sub MoveFolder()
'
' move any directories with all their contents listed in DIR_UPDATE from the source folder to the  Destination folder
'
  Dim objFSO As Object
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim sourceFolder As String
  Dim destinationFolder As String
  Dim mysql As String
  Dim DateFolder As String
  
  Dim objFolder, objSubFolders
  Dim UPdateFolder As String
  Dim sourceFolder0 As String, destinationFolder0 As String


  mysql = "SELECT * from [Update]"

  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(mysql)


  sourceFolder0 = "C:\Test"
  destinationFolder0 = "C:\Test\New"

  ' sourceFolder = "C:\Test\" & DateFolder & "\"
  ' destinationFolder = "C:\Test\New\" & DateFolder & "\"


  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sourceFolder0)
  Set objSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders

'
' loop over SubFolders to check them if they are DateFolder:
'
  For Each objFolder In objSubFolders
  
    '
    ' get SubFolder short name:
    '
    ' DateFolder = "20160331"
    '
    DateFolder = objFolder.Name
    
    '
    ' if it's a DateFolder in yyyymmdd format,
    ' eg 20160331, dir length = 8:
    '
    If (IsNumeric(DateFolder) And Len(DateFolder) = 8) Then

      '
      ' sourceFolder = "C:\Test\" & DateFolder & "\"
      ' destinationFolder = "C:\Test\New\" & DateFolder & "\"
      '
      sourceFolder = sourceFolder0 & "\" & DateFolder & "\"
      destinationFolder = destinationFolder0 & "\" & DateFolder & "\"

      '
      ' check if the destination exists:
      ' create it if nonexistent.
      '
      If (Not objFSO.FolderExists(destinationFolder)) Then
        objFSO.CreateFolder destinationFolder
      End If

      '
      ' look for folders from UPDATE and move them
      ' from sourcefolder to destinationFolder
      '
      While Not rs.EOF
      
        UPdateFolder = sourceFolder & rs!Update
 
        '
        ' must tell dir that sourceFolder is a directory:
        '
        If Dir(UPdateFolder, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
        
          objFSO.MoveFolder Source:=UPdateFolder, Destination:=destinationFolder
    
          Debug.Print "Move Folder Command Complete From: " _
            & UPdateFolder & "......To: " _
            & destinationFolder & rs!Update
 
        Else

        End If
    
        rs.MoveNext

      Wend
    
      '
      ' rewind recordset for the next DateFolder:
      '
      rs.MoveFirst
      '
      
    End If
    
  Next

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing

  Set objFolder = Nothing
  Set objSubFolders = Nothing

  Debug.Print "Move Complete " & Now()

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Appreciate your help jacouh! You helped also eliminate a separate robocopy piece I was having to do before code execution to create the date folder in the destination from the source (objFSO.CreateFolder destinationFolder).

Comment: It's great Scripting.FileSystemObject!